# Combining return values into a single type

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a Neo4j relationship that looks like this:

```
(a:Article)<-[:TRANSLATES]-(t:ArticleTranslation)
```

The `Article` label is applied to nodes which simply hold a unique identifier and the `ArticleTranslation` label is applied to nodes which contain:

- Title
- Body
- LanguageCode

I then have an `ICypherFluentQuery` that is constructed like so:

```
Match("(t:ArticleTranslation)-[:TRANSLATES]->(a:Article)")
    .Where("(a.Id = {id})")
    .AndWhere("(t.LanguageCode = {lang} OR (t.LanguageCode = 'en' and NOT a<--(:ArticleTranslation { LanguageCode: {lang} })))")
    .WithParams(new { id, lang })
```

From here, I understand that I can easily map `(a, t)` to an anonymous object containing two object instances such as:

```
new { Article = new Article { /* Article Properties */ },
    Translation = new ArticleTranslation { /* Translation Properties */ } }
```

However, in my application it is more useful (and intuitive) to work with *both* "article" and "translation" as a single entity, e.g.:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have managed to do this by adding the following:

```
.Return((a, t) => new Article
    {
        Id = a.As<Article>().Id,
        Title = t.As<Article>().Title,
        Body = t.As<Article>().Body,
        LanguageCode = t.As<Article>().LanguageCode
    });
```

However, this is unwieldy (especially when increasing the number of properties) and looks like it may invoke repeated mappings.

Is there a more succinct way of expressing this without introducing an independent `ArticleTranslation` entity?

Comment: Quick note in advance of anyone who thinks this might be better on CodeReview - I'm not asking for a critique of my current code; this is specifically a question about the `neo4jclient` API.

Comment: IN cypher you can create literal maps with `RETURN {id:a.id, title:t.title, body:t.body, code:t.languageCode}` Not sure how to consume that from neo4jclient though.

Comment: @MichaelHunger That's the part I can't quite reconcile - the fluent `Return` in my question roughly maps to that very return statement but the inputs to the Lambda are of type `ICypherResultItem` which leads to the need for the clunky `x.As<Y>()` mapping in order for the strongly-typed assignments to be possible. I'm sure there must be a cleaner way to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Neo4jClient to generate an arbitrary Cypher `RETURN` statement - and map it to the desired type - by passing in a parameterless delegate:

```
.Return(() => Return.As<ArticleTranslation>(
    "{ArticleId:a.Id, Title:t.Title, Body:t.Body, LanguageCode:t.LanguageCode}"))
```

In this example, the literal map is returned and then mapped to the `ArticleTranslation` type by Neo4jClient.